# It is not true that: "A conda package of Intel's optimized Tensorflow comes with the new 2018 Intel Python distribution on Linux."

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, intel

On the following web page:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimized-tensorflow-wheel-now-available

it is stated that:  "A conda package of Intel's optimized Tensorflow comes with the new 2018 Intel Python distribution on Linux."

I do not find this to be true.

---

On our cluster, we have:

Intel Parallel Studio XE 2018

In a separate install, we aquired:

Intel Deployment for Python (IDP) 2018 (2.7, 3.6).

---

Here is a screen capture containing the evidence that the optimized tensorflow did not come with IDP 2018:

```
[whowell@acf-knl004 ~]$ module load intel-python/2.7/2018.0.018
[whowell@acf-knl004 ~]$ which python
/global/opt/intel/python/2018.0.018/intelpython2/bin/python
[whowell@acf-knl004 ~]$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf;print          
tf.__file__;sess = tf.InteractiveSession()'
/global/opt/intel/python/2018.0.018/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-   
packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc
2017-10-09 18:28:23.284004: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow libra\ry 
wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-10-09 18:28:23.284243: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library 
wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-10-09 18:28:23.284311: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library 
wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-09 18:28:23.284456: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library     
wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-09 18:28:23.284518: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library 
wasn't compiled to use AVX512F instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-09 18:28:23.284579: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library 
wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

---

One of the optimizations was to build with vector instructions. Because we get a warning that the tensorflow used was not built with vector instructions, we must not be using the optimized version.

---

We have bioinformaticists with large distributed tensorflow runs to do, and new KNL's specifically for that purpose.  It is vital that we start with the optimized tensorflow for KNL.  We have individuals on our staff with several years of cutting edge research experience with both the Xeon Phi architecture,  and NVIDIA GPU's. It is likely there will be opportunities for collaboration in the future, to extend the tensorflow offering.

---

What do you suggest that we do next?

We greatly appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Dr. Mitch Horton
Joint Institute of Computational Science (JICS)
University of Tennessee, Knoxville, TN

Comment: To check if it's using runtime dispatching to select instruction sets (like @Yaroslav suggests), use `objdump -drwC -Mintel /usr/lib/.../whatever.so` and look for `zmm` registers and/or [`vfmadd` instructions (like `vfmadd213ps zmm11, zmm22, [rdi]`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VFMADD132PS_VFMADD213PS_VFMADD231PS.html))  If instructions like that exist anywhere in the binary, there's probably run-time dispatching to use them.

Comment: However, since tuning for KNL isn't the same as tuning for Skylake-AVX512, it probably makes sense to compile your own with `gcc -O3 -march=knl` (or `-march=native` if running the build on the KNL CPUs.  This `-march=native` might be the default for TensorFlow).  Unless you find a binary package that's specifically compiled for KNL, it will be at least slightly more optimal to build your own than to use libraries with run-time CPU detection that probably used `-mtune=generic`.  Unlike SKX, KNL is bad at legacy-SSE (decode bottlenecks), so make sure all your SIMD code uses AVX/AVX512.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the warnings are not legitimate. The reason is there are two ways of getting binary to use architecture specific instructions.

1. Fix an architecture and build everything with architecture specific flags (Google-way)
2. Use dynamic dispatch to pick the best instruction available for architecture during runtime. (rest-of-the-world way)

The warnings only check for way 1., they have no way of telling if Intel's operations are using dynamic dispatch logic to automatically select the best instruction for architecture.